# How can i check for text identical in textBox while typing inside the textBox?

Tags: c#

I have this Form:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace GatherLinks
{
    public partial class ChangeLink : Form
    {


        public ChangeLink()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        public string getText()
        {
            return textBox1.Text;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
            {
                DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
            }
            else
            {

            }

        }

        private void ChangeLink_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.AcceptButton = button1;
        } 

    }
}
```

And this code in Form1:

```
public void KeysValuesUpdate()
        {
            DialogResult dr = DialogResult.None;
            using (var w = new StreamWriter(keywords_path_file))
            {

                crawlLocaly1 = new CrawlLocaly(this);
                crawlLocaly1.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
                if (FormIsClosing != true)
                {
                    dr = crawlLocaly1.ShowDialog(this);
                }
                if (dr == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    if (LocalyKeyWords.ContainsKey(mainUrl))
                    {
                        LocalyKeyWords[mainUrl].Clear();
                        LocalyKeyWords[mainUrl].Add(crawlLocaly1.getText());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        LocalyKeyWords[mainUrl] = new List<string>();
                        LocalyKeyWords[mainUrl].Add(crawlLocaly1.getText());
                    }
                    Write(w);
                    ClearListBox();
                }
                if (dr == DialogResult.Cancel)
                {
                    Write(w);
                }
                if (dr == DialogResult.None)
                {
                    Write(w);
                }
            }
        }
```

This KeysValuesUpdate() function is called here:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cl = new ChangeLink();
            cl.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
            DialogResult dr = cl.ShowDialog(this);
            if (dr == DialogResult.Cancel)
            {
                cl.Close();
            }
            else if (dr == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                label4.Text = cl.getText();
                mainUrl = cl.getText();
                if (!LocalyKeyWords.ContainsKey(mainUrl))
                {
                    newUrl = true;
                    KeysValuesUpdate();
                }
                else
                {
                    newUrl = false;
                    KeysValuesUpdate();
                }
                OptionsDB.set_changeWebSite(cl.getText());
                cl.Close();
                listBox1.SelectedIndex = listBox1.Items.Count - 1;
            }
        }
```

When I click the button2 it's opening the new Form with a textbox and then inside I can type text.
Then I checking if the text inside already exist then newUrl is false or true.
Then when I click OK the OK button in the new Form then it's checking if the text I typed Contain/exist already or not.

I want that when the user type something in the textbox while he is typing if it's Contain/Exist the key then color the text in the textbox in Red one the user is keep typing and the text is not Contain/EXist color it back to Black but each time if the text in the textbox Contain/Exist already color it in Red and only if it's match case not if the text is inside other text:

This is in black:
For example : Danny hello all

But if I type in the textbox only: hello 
Then the word hello will be in Red then if I kept typing after the hello then all the text in the textbox is Black if I delete the text and kept only the word hello then it will be Red again.

And that should be according to the code above and in realtime when im typing text in the textbox.

The new Form again with updated code with the textBox1 text changed event:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace GatherLinks
{
    public partial class ChangeLink : Form
    {
        Form1 f1;

        public ChangeLink(Form1 f)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            f1 = f;
        }

        public string getText()
        {
            return textBox1.Text;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
            {
                DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
            }
            else
            {

            }

        }

        private void ChangeLink_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.AcceptButton = button1;
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (f1.mainUrl.Contains(textBox1.Text))
            {
                textBox1.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            }
            else
                textBox1.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        } 

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Regex.IsMatch(yourtext, @"\b" + textBox.Text + @"\b"))
            {
                textBox.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            }
            else
                textBox.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        }
```

Place your data containing variable name at the place of `yourtext`.

I have edited the answer. It is perfectly matching the whole words as you asked to do. To use `Regex` class, include `System.Text.RegularExpressions` namesapce.

Comment: Shaharyar it's working. And if I want extact match I mean now if I the word ot be Red is danny so now if I type only d the letter d is already in Red  I want that only if I typed the exact word danny only then it will color in red then if I deleted one letter dann then it's black again almost lke it is now but exact word and only a part of the word.

Comment: In in which pattern your matching data is? I mean are you matching the words in any list? any paragraph? or something else?

Comment: Shaharyar I changed the variable mainUrl in Form1 to be public and call it in the text changed event in the other Form. mainUrl is string wich get the text im typing from the textbox. You can see the mainUrl above in the code in my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement textBox1 **TextChanged** event handler simply by defining a method

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var textBox = sender as TextBox;
    String text = textBox.Text;
    if (SomeCheck(text))
    {
        textBox.ForeColor = Color.Red;
    }
    else
    {
        textBox.ForeColor = Color.Black;
    }
}
```

and assigning method `textBox1_TextChanged` to `OnTextChanged` property of textBox